# MongoDB: update only specific fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to update a row in a (typed) MongoDB collection with the C# driver. When handling data of that particular collection of type `MongoCollection<User>`, I tend to avoid retrieving sensitive data from the collection (salt, password hash, etc.)

Now I am trying to update a `User` instance. However, I never actually retrieved sensitive data in the first place, so I guess this data would be `default(byte[])` in the retrieved model instance (as far as I can tell) before I apply modifications and submit the new data to the collection.

Maybe I am overseeing something trivial in the MongoDB C# driver how I can use `MongoCollection<T>.Save(T item)` without updating specific properties such as `User.PasswordHash` or `User.PasswordSalt`? Should I retrieve the full record first, update "safe" properties there, and write it back? Or is there a fancy option to exclude certain fields from the update?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Save(someValue) is for the case where you want the resulting record to be or become the full object (someValue) you passed in.

You can use

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id","123");
var sortBy = SortBy.Null;
var update = Update.Inc("LoginCount",1).Set("LastLogin",DateTime.UtcNow); // some update, you can chain a series of update commands here

MongoCollection<User>.FindAndModify(query,sortby,update);
```

method.

Using FindAndModify you can specify exactly which fields in an existing record to change and leave the rest alone.

You can see an example [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#findandmodify-method).

The only thing you need from the existing record would be its _id, the 2 secret fields need not be loaded or ever mapped back into your POCO object.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But my underlying problem still exists: I wish to update all properties from my typed `MongoCollection<T>` with the values of an instance of `T`, except a specific known set of fields. Something along the lines of `Update<T>.EverythingFrom(someObject).Except(x => x.ExceptThis).Except(x => x.ExceptThat)`

Comment: This is a custom job you would need to write (EverythingFrom..). Not too hard to do on the client side, by walking the BsonMemberMap and getting all mapped members, then only building an Update.Set() from each if you know that value changed. It is not guaranteed coherent since the DB may have changed since you read the record into memory though.

Answer (score 6):

It´s possible to add more criterias in the Where-statement. Like this:

```
var db = ReferenceTreeDb.Database;
var packageCol = db.GetCollection<Package>("dotnetpackage");
var filter = Builders<Package>.Filter.Where(_ => _.packageName == packageItem.PackageName.ToLower() && _.isLatestVersion);
var update = Builders<Package>.Update.Set(_ => _.isLatestVersion, false);
var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Package>();
packageCol.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options);
```

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem and since I wanted to have 1 generic method for all types and didn't want to create my own implementation using Reflection, I end up with the following generic solution (simplified to show all in one method):

```
Task<bool> Update(string Id, T item)
{
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
            };
    var bson = new BsonDocument() { { "$set", BsonDocument.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, serializerSettings)) } };
    await database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName).UpdateOneAsync(Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", Id), bson);
}
```

Notes:

- Make sure all fields that must not update are set to default value.
- If you need to set field to default value, you need to either use DefaultValueHandling.Include, or write custom method for that update
- When performance matters, write custom update methods using `Builders<T>.Update`

  P.S.: It's obviously should have been implemented by MongoDB .Net Driver, however I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs, maybe I just looked the wrong way.

Comment: Helped me a lot, but it's better to use `item.ToBsonDocument()` instead of `BsonDocument.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, serializerSettings))`

Comment: I remember I couldn't make ToBsonDocument exclude default values, that's why I used JsonConvert. Maybe it works better in newer version or I overlooked settings

Comment: I used  the decorator `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` on model properties, so, probably, that's why it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Well there are many ways to updated value in `mongodb`.

Below is one of the simplest way I choose to update a field value in mongodb collection.

```
public string UpdateData()
        {               
            string data = string.Empty;
            string param= "{$set: { name:'Developerrr New' } }";
            string filter= "{ 'name' : 'Developerrr '}";
            try
            {  
               //******get connections values from web.config file*****
                var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
                var databseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"];
                var tableName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["table"];

                //******Connect to mongodb**********
                var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
                var dataBases = client.GetDatabase(databseName);
                var dataCollection = dataBases.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(tableName);       

                //****** convert filter and updating value to BsonDocument*******
                BsonDocument filterDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(filter);
                BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(param);

                //********Update value using UpdateOne method*****
                dataCollection.UpdateOne(filterDoc, document);                   
                data = "Success";
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                data = "Failed - " + err;
            }
            return data;    
        }
```

**Hoping this will help you :)**