# update cant change record in mongodb database using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, mongodb

this is my c# code

```
public static void updateSubmit(string id,string fname,string lname,string email,string password,string address)
{
    string connectionString = "mongodb://10.10.32.125:27017";
       MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
       MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
       var Server = mongoClient.GetDatabase("mongovaibhav");
       var collection = Server.GetCollection<employee>("mongov");
       ObjectId objectId = ObjectId.Parse(id);
       var filter = Builders<employee>.Filter.Eq(s => s._id, objectId);
       employee emp = new employee();
       emp.fname = fname;
       emp.lname = lname;
       emp.email = email;
       emp.pass = password;
       emp.address = address;
       collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, emp);
}
```

This is my ajax code with whom i send update request and data also

```
 function updateSubmit()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'Home.aspx/updateSubmit',
            data: "{'id':'" + $("#hidden").val()+ "','fname':'" + $("#fname").val() + "','lname':'" + $("#lname").val() + "','email':'" + $("#email").val() + "','password':'" + $("#password").val() + "','address':'" + $("address").val() + "'}",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("You Have SuccessFully Update Data");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('there is some error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Now My Problem is that i get the alert message that you have successfully update record but the record cant change effect in database

Comment: I am not sure on the exact cause but you can check the AJAX response details in the success callback function.

Comment: is the collection.replaceoneasyc is the right method or i can use any other method

Comment: You can check this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853362/mongodb-update-only-specific-fields

Comment: To verify whether your code sends the correct command to the DB: (1) enable DB profiling with db.setProfilingLevel(2) -- this will make the DB log every command it executes in "system.profile" collection -- see more in the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel (2) execute your request, and inspect the "system.profile" collection to see what command the DB executed, and whether it is what you intended to do.  Try re-running that command manually. Is it what you intended to do? You'll get much clearer understanding from that point.

Comment: i try excet same way which you refer me @souvik ghosh and i aslo debug the value but the data does not tack change effect

Answer (score 0):

i Got the Solution  i have Mistake In My "Param" Variable Where I Write Password Insted of "pass" because my employee class contain "pass" property 
Thank you every one @souvik @felix

```
  string connectionString = "mongodb://10.10.32.125:27017";
            MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
            var Server = mongoClient.GetDatabase("mongovaibhav");
            var collection = Server.GetCollection<employee>("mongov");
            ObjectId objectId = ObjectId.Parse(id);
              var filter = Builders<employee>.Filter.Eq(s => s._id, objectId);   
            string param = "{$set: { fname:'" + fname + "',lname:'" + lname + "',email:'" + email + "',pass:'" + password + "',address :'" + address + "' } }";
            BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(param);
            collection.UpdateMany(filter, document);
```